# XPATH logic AND - how?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
(//table[@id="primenimost_table"]/tbody//tr/td[3] and //table[@id="primenimost_table"]/tbody//tr/td[4])
```

This formula doesn't work.

Example HTML:

```
<table id="primenimost_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>FORD</td>
            <td>C-MAX II (DXA/CB7, DXA/CEU)</td>
            <td>1.6 TDCi</td>
            <td>12.2010 - </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>FORD</td>
            <td>GRAND C-MAX (DXA/CB7, DXA/CEU)</td>
            <td>1.6 Ti</td>
            <td>12.2010 - </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Need parse
1.6 TDCi 12.2010 -
1.6 Ti 12.2010 -

Comment: can you please share the html on which you are trying this xpath.

Comment: hello, yes, add sample code

Comment: which language and tool you are using? obviously your xpath did not worked because of `AND` which will check for both the conditions to be matched and as always both those conditions does not match.

Comment: C#, tool name - Datacol - desktop constructor for web-scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//table[@id="primenimost_table"]/tbody/tr/td[position() = 3 or position() = 4]
```

will select all 3rd and 4th `td` elements in each `tr` of the id'ed `table`.

(Although you want the 3rd ***and*** 4th elements, it's actually a logical ***or*** against the positions that yields the desired elements.)